# Is it OK to use the same local branch forever

Tags: git, merge, rebase, pull-request

We recently switched to git from Team Foundation Version Control.  I've found a tendency among our development team to want to make a local branch off of local master, call it local-dev, and then use that branch forever.  We are using a pull request process so they push their local-dev onto the server and perform a pull-request onto master.

When the pull-request completes, they delete the server-dev branch but keep their local-dev branch.  They just pull the latest into their local master, and then merge local master into local-dev.  Then repeat the cycle.

Is this an OK thing to do?  In my head I see that since their local-dev is never being rebased, they are continuously pushing all history since day 1 onto the server every time they do a pull request and are forcing the server to handle that merge.  Which seems to work OK.

Is this a ticking time-bomb?  Is this perfectly acceptable and I'm worried about nothing?  What is the server doing to handle this merge?

Comment: `In my head I see that since their local-dev is never being rebased` this is where your assumption falls apart, they will be required to fetch from the origin once the pull-request is completed else they will have diverged from the server.

Comment: They do a merge from master into their local-dev.  But that just creates a new commmit-merge node inside of their local-dev branch is my understanding.   Rebasing at the least would allow the history to start from the last known merge on master, but since they do a merge, the branch history remains at day 1.  Isn't that right?

Comment: Oh, that's just dirty. There is no real _issue_ if it works, but it's wrong. You should generally create new feature branches for each new commit to master. Do your work in however many commit it takes, and if you can, rebase along the way. Just before CR, squash to a single commit, and that single commit is what will be merged to master for the feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git uses revision walking to negotiate a common set of commits on both sides.  So if, during a push, the client side knows what the server's `master` branch is, then it will be able to eliminate anything it contains from being sent, including the old version of the `local-dev` branch.

The workflow that's being used isn't necessarily inefficient for pushes, but repeated criss-cross merges between `master` and the `local-dev` branch make `git log --topo-order` *very* slow.  So while it may not be a problem for inexperienced Git users, it will make advanced users a little unhappy since it causes some slowness in advanced operations.  It also creates an untidy history, which some people feel strongly about.

In addition, this workflow prevents having multiple branches in flight at once.  A developer might need to wait to merge a branch because the subject matter expert is on vacation and can't give a review, and creating a new branch would allow working on a different piece of work while waiting for that review.

The typical workflow is to create a new, uniquely named branch for the feature or bug fix in question, make changes, and push that up.  The local branch can be discarded when the server branch is merged (or kept if the person prefers).

So ultimately the answer is that this is not a typical workflow and it causes a few practical problems, but it isn't hugely problematic.  It wouldn't be a problem to educate your users, but it's up to you whether you think it's important enough to enforce in policy.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for.  The revision walking makes it such that this is a non-issue technically.  The team is using Windows and Visual Studio so they aren't yet accustomed to using git log.  They use the tools built into Visual Studio for viewing history.  We just transitioned about four weeks ago.  I was responsible for the migration and didn't know if this practice was going to lead to issues.

Answer (score 0):

If they are rebasing origin/master every time they pick up a few feature, then there's not that much harm as the full history of their own local-dev branch is shared with master.

But if they are doing the opposite, and are in fact doing a forced-pushed on master and full rewrites, then yes I would argue that they are using the tool incorrectly. If this were the case, I imagine they would also need to resolve the same conflicts over and over again.

Rebases aren't *that* harmful on short-lived feature branches, but I would probably never want to allow them (or force-pushes) on master unless it's to repair something after someone broke it.

Comment: My understanding is that the best practice is to just delete your local branch after the successful pull-request and start working on a new one.  I think they don't think of Git as a timeline of commits.  They think it is just going to magically merge their latest source changes since the last merge.

Comment: If your local branch is an exact copy of the 'current master' (using `git reset --hard origin/master`) then it's effectively the same as just cutting a new branch. A bit strange to do this instead of making a new branch, but not extremely harmful.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **NO**.

A suggested method.

- A new branch should be created as new branch. Developer must work on that branch
- Pull request should be done with either development or master branch. I dropped development branch and create pull request with master branch. And permission to merge with master is limited, so risk get mitigated. If there was no option, I would have keep development branch and create pull request with development branch.
- After Approval and before release create release branch from master, create pull request with from feature branch to release branch, approve, merge.
- Release the release branch
- Create a pull request with master branch and development(if you have) branch
- When product manager or producer are satisfied with the release create pull request from release to master and move on with your life

```sql
                     Release branch
                /--------- <- Release ------------ 
master branch  /        /merge with release  \  \  merge feature with master
-----------------------/-----------------------  \
               \ Feat / ure branch                \
                \---------------                   \
                      \  for review purpose only    \
development branch     \   (parallel to master)      \ merge feature with dev
------------------------------------------------------------
```

sorry, look messy